# Creating a variable of an object type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been stuck on this problem and can't seem to get my head around it, I'm creating a program in C++ that calculates various functions such as area, perimeter, points of different shapes.

Part of this includes creating a leftTop variable of Point type (Point is a class that simply has 2 ints (x and y) and a method called Point to print out the x and y of different shapes). I've used a template to create a function of point type that simply returns x and y, I know this is incorrect but thought I'd try it anyway.

```
template <typename Point>
Point leftTop(Point x, Point y) {
    return x, y;
}
```

But it needs to be a data member of point type (stored in a class called shape) that is used to store the x and y coordinates of the left top point of the shape and I'm stuck on how to implement this, as I need to use the leftTop variable to calculate the other points of the shape such as leftBottom, rightTop, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the ```x``` and ```y``` parameters be ```int```s? And that return statement as written doesn't return both ```x``` and ```y```, the ```,``` operator returns its right operand, so your return does basically the same thing as ```return y```. I believe what you want to do is ```return {x, y};``` after changing ```x``` and ```y``` to be ```int```s.

Comment: sound like `topLeft` should be a (possibly virtual) non-template member function of your `Shape` class.

Comment: you can also look at the design of [`QRect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html) and its [`topLeft`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#topLeft).

Comment: Hey thomas, according to my specification it cant be a member function it has to be a data member to store the x and y coordinates of the left top of the shape, i will then also use this to calculate the other points of the shape too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making things over-complicated by using a templated function! The *exact* solution depends on how you have defined your `Point` class, but you probably just need a relevant constructor:

```cpp
class Point
{
public
    Point(int px, int py) : x{ px }, y{ py } {}
public: // Make these "private" if you want to prevent direct access
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And then you can create your `leftTop` object very easily:

```cpp
int left = 12; // Or whatever
int top = 17;
Point leftTop(left, top);
```

You can add other member functions to do pretty much anything else you'd care to.

As you're using Visual Studio, and thus may have access to the MFC classes, you could maybe take a look at how MFC implements its `CPoint` and `CRect` classes for guidance. If you can't get to see the MFC stuff, then the `Windows.h` file provides C-style structs called `POINT` and `RECT` that could also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just have a question on how i would be able to print out the variables passed into the parameters of leftTop, thank you again.

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 There a many ways: you could add a `print` member function to your `Point` class that uses `cout << x << y` to display its `x` and `y` members.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would i be able to somehow print the leftTop object as id also have to print out the rightTop object which will be created later and that would be printing out x+width and y, thanks

Comment: @OpenSourcerer42 This can all be done, of course, but that would most likely be the 'job' of your `Shape` class - which would have `Point` objects as its members: for a rectangle, `topLeft` and `bottomRight` members would be sufficient, and you could have a constructor of the form `Shape(x, y, w, h)` which would set those members accordingly.

Comment: Thats great thank you, ill implement this when im back home and update the thread with the results!

Comment: Hey, ive tried to implement it by adding a cout in the 'Point(int px, int py)' in Point.h and then creating a data member as 'Point leftTop(int x, int y)' in shape.h and then calling that in rectangle.cpp by typing 'leftTop(Point::x, Point::y)' to pass in the x and y values of the shape but i get an unresolved external symbol (LNK2019) in rhe .obj of the rectangle.cpp file

Comment: If you declare a member in your `Shape` class as `Point leftTop(int x, int y);` then it is declaring a *function* member - which (presumably) you haven't defined anywhere. Just declare it as `Point leftTop` then, when you construct your `Shape` object (let's call it `shape1`) you can (somewhere) assign to `leftTop` with: `shape1`.leftTop = Point(x, y);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203814/discussion-between-opensourcerer42-and-adrian-reinstate-monica).